# Insight into heavy or currently-running queries on Influx v2.x

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

In my Influx v2.x setup, I have a process that is running frequent periodic queries that eat up a lot of resources. I want to identify the query that's executed, which may be coming from several consumers/apps.

For example, in Influx v1.x you are able to execute `SHOW QUERIES` to show the [currently running queries](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/troubleshooting/query_management/).
But for Influx v2.x I can't find any mention of query management in the docs.

How can I gather insights in exactly what these heavy (running or historic) queries are, on Influx v2.x?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Below is a lacking workaround and I would **not consider this an answer** to my original question. But it's better than nothing.

There is one way: enable the `query-log-enabled` option in the influx config:

```
  # Whether queries should be logged before execution. Very useful for troubleshooting, 
  # but will log any sensitive data contained within a query.
    query-log-enabled = true
```

This will output all queries to the Influx logs. The logs can then be extracted and analysed, even with a third party tool, to find at least some information:

```
2022-07-08 15:22:09 
10.106.76.204 - - [08/Jul/2022:17:22:09 +0200] "POST /write?db=devices&rp=Device HTTP/1.1 " 204 0 "-" "Telegraf/1.22.0-ffaa5ce2 Go/1.17.7" bbda5938-0050569b87e2 51819
2022-07-08 15:22:09 
10.106.76.203 - - [08/Jul/2022:17:22:09 +0200] "POST /write?db=devices&rp=Device HTTP/1.1 " 204 0 "-" "Telegraf/1.22.0-ffaa5ce2 Go/1.17.7" bbca1d6f-0050569b87e2 58187
2022-07-08 15:22:08 
10.106.76.205 - - [08/Jul/2022:17:22:08 +0200] "POST /write?db=devices&rp=Device HTTP/1.1 " 204 0 "-" "Telegraf/1.22.0-ffaa5ce2 Go/1.17.7" bb2bea51-0050569b87e2 95342
```

Downside is that the reported logs are on this higher level. There aren't any stats on duration or weight (size) of each request.

That still makes it hard to pinpoint the heavy queries, per original question. And grabbing logs is also far from ideal, as the perfect answer would be to do this using an Influx query - in Influx environment itself, not on the server.